# Enabling the Gzip Compression in sharepoint Office365

Tags: performance, sharepoint, gzip, office365

Basically I want to compress all js and css in sharepoint office 365, so is there any way to do it via Gzip compression?

OR

Is there any way to merge and minify js and css in sharepoint office 365?

Answer (score 0):

All the page components that can be, are already using Gzip compression. You can verify this by the following steps:

1. Download the web proxy tool [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler)
2. Enable Decryption of HTTPS traffic by following the [steps described here](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS).
3. Visit a page on Office 365 and examine the individual page component "sessions". If you look at the Headers for those sessions, you will see **Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate** indicated.

   4. Custom CSS & other branding assets will be Gzip'd automatically as well.

OOTB CSS on Office 365 also seems to be minimized across the board. If you are deploying custom CSS, then you can simply minify locally prior to publishing.

Please note that since the [Minimal Download Strategy Site Feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn456544.aspx) is on by default in Office 365 SharePoint sites, you should take care to cater any custom Master Pages to accommodate the requirements of that system, or else you will actually make performance worse by inflicting an extra page load cycle.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I just discovered that if you have a querystring in your references to your assets files like JS and CSS - perhaps a version number for cache-busting reasons - SPO evidently does NOT Gzip the file.

I assume this is to do with the 'Output Cache Settings' in SPO, which say that: `the system administrator has configured output cache values for the following settings: ..., *vary by query string parameters*`.

So if you have something like `/path/filename.js?v=1`, then remove the `?v=1` and your file(s) should be GZip'd.